# Branch and Price in SCIP

Tags: c++, scip

I have a question about branching in the branch & price using SCIP. Does SCIP normally branch on the original variables? For example, in the VRP example, does it branch on the master problem variables or the original ones?
If I want to branch on the original variables, do I need to add my own branching rule?

Comment: According to Barnhart, it is better to branch on the master problem variables, because "A compact formulation of a MIP may have a symmetric structure that causes branch-and-bound to perform poorly because the problem barely changes after branching.  A reformulation with a huge number of variables can eliminate this symmetry."

Answer (score 2):

When talking about SCIP alone, SCIP will by default just branch on the variables present in the model (which are your master variables when doing branch-and-price). The VRP example is just a very brief example for a pricer, and does not implement a problem-specific branching rule. In general, however, it is highly recommended to implement your own problem specific branching rule, as it is done in the Coloring and the Binpacking example. They both implement a Ryan&Foster branching.

Ben is right that branching on the original variables itself is often a bad idea, since this might reintroduce symmetry. However, branching on the master variables themselves is normally as bad, since there is a hugh number of them and only very few will be nonzero, so the branching will be very unbalances. And after fixing a variable to zero, you must make sure that the branching won't generate a copy of this variable again.
Therefore, my recommendation is to branch on original variables if there is no symmetry or on constraints (originating from the original problem) like it is done by the Ryan-Foster branching rule.

Alternatively, you should have a look at GCG, which already implements a generic branch-and-price including generic branching rules. You need to read your original model into GCG, which will then do the Dantzig-Wolfe reformulation based on a structure you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [GCG](http://www.or.rwth-aachen.de/gcg/) or just SCIP?
There are already some [branching rules for branch-and-price available in GCG](http://www.or.rwth-aachen.de/gcg/doc/group__BRANCHINGRULES.html). I recommend that you check these out and see whether that is what you are looking for.